# woocommerce plugin bugs

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

I have some problems with displaying some values and I have no idea what I did wrong.

```
    <?php
/*
 Plugin Name: Wallet for WooCommerce
 Plugin URI:
 Description: Wallet for a Client
 Version: 1.0
 Author: InDeepTerror
 Author URI:
 */

 include( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'wallet.php');
include( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'settings.php');


$wallet = New wallet();

 add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'getPerProduct');

 add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'save_wallet_option');

?>

<?php
```

/**
 * Class wallet
 *
 * @param int $customer_id Current customer ID
 *
 */

class wallet {

```
function __construct()
{
        if ($this->checkEcommerce()) {
            add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'account_menu_hook');
            add_filter( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'account_wallet_menu');
            add_action( 'woocommerce_account_wallet-endpoint', 'displayWallet');
            add_action( 'wp_login', 'walletOwner', 99);
            add_action( 'woocommerce_created_customer', 'createPointsField');
} else
            throw new Exception('WooCommerce is not Installed. The plugin Requires WooCommerce', 7);
}

function checkEcommerce() {
    if ( in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) ) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

function walletOwner($login) {
$user = get_user_by('login',$login);
    $user_id = $user->ID;
    return $user_id;
}

function displayWallet() {
/*    $userID = $this->walletOwner();
    $this->getUserPoints($userID);
echo "<span> <b>". $amount . "</b> </span>"
;*/
echo "TEST!";
}
function newMenuWP($pagetitle, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function, $position, $icon_url) {
    add_menu_page( $pagetitle, $menu_title, $capability, $menu_slug, $function, $icon_url, $position );
}
function getPerPrice($percentage) {

}
function WPMenu(){
    echo '';
}
function getPerCategory($points) {

}
function getPerProduct() {
    global $woocommerce, $post;

    echo '<div class="options_group">';

    woocommerce_wp_text_input(
        array(
            'id'    => '_number_field',
            'label' => __( 'MoneyBack Wallet', 'woocommerce' ),
            'placeholder' => '',
            'description' => __( 'Enter the product percentage points'),
            'type'        => 'number',
            'custom_attributes' => array(
                'step' => '0.1',
                'min'  => '0',
                'max'  => '100',
            )
        )
    );

    echo '</div>';
}
function isAffiliate($product_id) {

}
function SignUpBonus($bonus) {

}
function setSignUpBonus($bonus_amount) {

}
function addPoints($add_points) {

}
function convertPoints($points)
{

}

function save_wallet_option()
{
    $woocommerce_number_field = $_POST['_number_field'];
    if (!empty($woocommerce_number_field)) {
        update_post_meta($post_id, '_number_field', esc_attr($woocommerce_number_field));
    }
}
function account_menu_hook($items) {
$items['wallet-endpoint'] = __('Wallet EndPoint', 'woocommerce');
    return $items;
}
function account_menu_insert_position($items, $new_items, $location) {
    $position = array_search( $after, array_keys( $items ) );
    $array = array_slice( $items, 0, $position, true );
    $array += $new_items;
    $array += array_slice( $items, $position, count( $items ) - $position, true );

    return $array;
}
function account_wallet_menu($items) {
    $new_items = array();
    $new_items['wallet-endpoint'] = __('Wallet EndPoint', 'woocommerce');

    return $this->account_menu_insert_position($items, $new_items, 'dashboard');
}
function getUserPoints($user_id) {

  $points = get_user_meta($user_id, 'points', true);

  if (!isset($points)) {
      $this->createPointsField();
      return $points = $this->SignUpBonus();
  }

    return $points;
}
function createPointsField($customer_id) {
add_user_meta($customer_id, 'points', $this->SignUpBonus());
}
```

}
?>

The errors I get in add new product:

> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid
>   callback, function 'getPerProduct' not found or invalid function name
>   in /home/styleadda/developers.styleadda.in/wp-includes/plugin.php on
>   line 524

The errors I get in myaccount:

> > Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'account_menu_hook' not found or invalid function
> >     name in /home/styleadda/developers.styleadda.in/wp-includes/plugin.php
> >     on line 235
>
> Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid
>   callback, function 'account_wallet_menu' not found or invalid function
>   name in /home/styleadda/developers.styleadda.in/wp-includes/plugin.php
>   on line 235
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /home/styleadda/developers.styleadda.in/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/myaccount/navigation.php
>   on line 28

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to correct how you call function in your class, if the function you want to use is in the class, for the add_action:
     add_action( 'woocommerce_account_wallet-endpoint', array($this, 'displayWallet') );
            add_action( 'wp_login', array($this, 'walletOwner'), 99);

Replace all add_action or filter like this.